# C++ - QListWidget select first item

Tags: c++, qt, qlistwidget

In my `QMainWindow` Constructor I read a database and fill my `QListWidget` with the items. Apparently there is no item selected so I have to do it on my own. I also have a slot which will be called when I **click** on an item in the list.

I tried `setCurrentRow( const int )` but if I do so the slot won't be called. I've seen the function setCurrentIndex( const QModelIndex & ) but I'm not familiar with the QModelIndex.

How do I tell my QListWidget to select the first item and call the `on_list_clicked(const QModelIndex& index)` slot?

Edit:
Also, I cannot use any other slot than clicked because `currentRowChanged(int)` and `itemSelectionChanged()` both make my program crash when I remove a certain index from the list.

So somehow I need to perform a click on the list...

Comment: Why not call setCurrentRow() and emit on_list_clicked(const QModelIndex& index) from your constructor? I.e., call QListWidget::currentItemChanged() after QListWidget::setCurrentItem.

Comment: @sashoalm well I could emit it but I need a QModelIndex for it. And that's the problem, I don't know how to create a QModelIndex the correct way... tried everything but it won't compile.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Calling `setCurrentRow()` emits the signal `currentRowChanged()`, which accepts an `int` instead of a `QModelIndex`.

Simply connect to that signal instead of to `itemSelectionChanged()`.

Sample code:

```
MainWindow::MainWindow(QWidget *parent) :
    QMainWindow(parent),
    ui(new Ui::MainWindow)
{
    ui->setupUi(this);
    ui->listWidget->setCurrentRow(1);
}

void MainWindow::on_listWidget_currentRowChanged(int currentRow)
{
    qDebug() << currentRow;
}
```

Comment: I can't. When I remove a certain item from the list the program crashes. I have a QList which holds the information from a database. The row in the QListWidget is the current item in QList. When I change a row I want this information to be displayed in a few labels etc. So when I remove an item from the QList, then remove it from the QListWidget it tries to display the information of a row which may not exist anymore and causes a crash.

Comment: Nevermind, thank you. I somehow messed up at some point, fixed it. Now your suggest using currentRow works. :) Thanks a lot.