# How to show proper QStackedWidget page after QListWidget selection

Tags: c++11, qt5, qlistwidget, qstackedwidget

I have `1 QListWidget` and `1 QStackedWidget`. The `QstackedWidget` has three different widgets to be shown after selecting the entriesd on the `QListWidget`.

**The problem:** as I select the first choice nothing happens and nothing happens if I select the second choice, but when I select the last choice I see the widget on the `QStackedWidget`. This widget does not appartain to the third widget but it appartain to the first widget.

Signals of [QListWidget::currentRowChanged([C++ - QListWidget select first item](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18596260/c-qlistwidget-select-first-item)) does not seem to be triggered correctly. Why is that happening? Basically seems to be triggered only the last choice instead all the others.

Below the snippet of code:

**1 solution:** works partially because out of three choices I can only see the last `QWidget` showing on the `QStackedWidget`:

```
OptionsDialog::OptionsDialog(QWidget *parent) :
    QDialog(parent),
    ui(new Ui::OptionsDialog)
{
    ui->setupUi(this);

    mVesPos = new VesselPosSystemWidget;
    mSonar = new SonarForm;
    mOutput = new OutputForm;
    ui->stackedWidget->addWidget(mVesPos);
    ui->stackedWidget->addWidget(mSonar);
    ui->stackedWidget->addWidget(mOutput);

    ui->horizontalLayout->addWidget(ui->stackedWidget);
    setLayout(ui->horizontalLayout);


    QObject::connect(ui->listWidget, &QListWidget::currentRowChanged,
            ui->stackedWidget, &QStackedWidget::setCurrentIndex);
}

OptionsDialog::~OptionsDialog()
{
    delete ui;
}
```

**2 solution:** works partially because out of three choices I can only see the last `QWidget` showing on the `QStackedWidget`. This solution was taken from [official documentation of QStackedWidget](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qstackedwidget.html#details):

```
OptionsDialog::OptionsDialog(QWidget *parent) :
    QDialog(parent),
    ui(new Ui::OptionsDialog)
{
    ui->setupUi(this);

    mVesPos = new VesselPosSystemWidget;
    mSonar = new SonarForm;
    mOutput = new OutputForm;
    ui->stackedWidget->addWidget(mVesPos);
    ui->stackedWidget->addWidget(mSonar);
    ui->stackedWidget->addWidget(mOutput);

    ui->horizontalLayout->addWidget(ui->stackedWidget);
    setLayout(ui->horizontalLayout);


    connect(ui->listWidget, QOverload<int>::of(&QListWidget::currentRowChanged),
        ui->stackedWidget, &QStackedWidget::setCurrentIndex);

}

OptionsDialog::~OptionsDialog()
{
    delete ui;
}
```

**3 solution:** same exact effect, only the third `QWidget` is shown:

```
OptionsDialog::OptionsDialog(QWidget *parent) :
    QDialog(parent),
    ui(new Ui::OptionsDialog)
{
    ui->setupUi(this);

    mVesPos = new VesselPosSystemWidget;
    mSonar = new SonarForm;
    mOutput = new OutputForm;
    ui->stackedWidget->addWidget(mVesPos);
    ui->stackedWidget->addWidget(mSonar);
    ui->stackedWidget->addWidget(mOutput);

    ui->horizontalLayout->addWidget(ui->stackedWidget);
    setLayout(ui->horizontalLayout);


    connect(ui->listWidget, &QListWidget::currentRowChanged,
        [=](int index) { on_listWidget_currentRowChanged(index); });


}

OptionsDialog::~OptionsDialog()
{
    delete ui;
}

void OptionsDialog::on_listWidget_currentRowChanged(int currentRow)
{
    ui->stackedWidget->setCurrentIndex(currentRow);
}
```

I don't know what else to try to have the `.ui` forms switch after selcting the item in the `QListWidget`. Is there something I am missing? I tried all possible `connect` combinations but despite that I can only show the third choice.

Comment: did you debug your code? put a break point in on_listWidget_currentRowChanged function and check the values of `currentRow`. I don't have a qt setup thus I cannot check your code.

Comment: thanks for reading the question. Yes I added `qDebug() << currentRow;` and the result is 0. See [here](https://i.imgur.com/QtJDwvz.png). Is this telling you something?

Comment: In addition as you see [here](https://i.imgur.com/ZuOvxIJ.png) the selection of the `QListWidget` entry is correct. But I only see the last `.ui` form appearing on the `QStackedWidget`. I am not sure what is happening.

Comment: ok, let's start from scratch. try to put very basic widgets (label, push button etc.) into stacked widget and change the index. see if it's changing as expected.

Comment: @seleciii44, following your advice I started with a basic example e started from there. I found the solution to this question and posted a detailed answer below so that other users can benefit from it.

Comment: Also I don't understand why someone down-voted the question though. It took me a while to extract the most important part of the info from the code and a big effort to try to pose the question in an understandable way.

Comment: You are very nice and thank you for your time in point me to where the error was! :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I hope this could be useful for other users. I found a solution to this question. It was not easy and it required reading in depth the official documentation. Basically what was happening was that as I tried to select the proper `QWidget` on the `QlistWidget`, the selection was erroneously going to the incorrect form. I tried to

```
qDebug() << ui->stackedWidget->addWidget(mSonar);
qDebug() << ui->stackedWidget->addWidget(mOutput);
```

And was obtaining index 3,4,5. Which explains why I was only seeing the last index.
Now after long and in-depth reading of the documentation I found out about `QStackedWidget::insertWidget` relationships with all possible `QWidget` you want to link to the stack. It basically linking all the views to the form under the precise condition that what you are passing are `QWidgets`. So for example if you would like to link a `QDialog` to the `QStackedWidget` this is not allowed, because `QStackedWidgets` inherits `QWidgets`. 
Therefore the solution was to insert the correct widget right from the beginning passing the proper index manually (in my case).

Code solution:

```
OptionsDialog::OptionsDialog(QWidget *parent) :
    QDialog(parent),
    ui(new Ui::OptionsDialog)
{
    ui->setupUi(this);
    mVesPos = new VesselPosSystemWidget;
    mSonar = new SonarForm;
    mOutput = new OutputForm;
    ui->stackedWidget->insertWidget(0, mVesPos);
    ui->stackedWidget->insertWidget(1, mSonar);
    ui->stackedWidget->insertWidget(2, mOutput);

    // This is how to link the choice according to the latest signals notation
    connect(ui->listWidget, &QListWidget::currentRowChanged,
            ui->stackedWidget, &QStackedWidget::setCurrentIndex);
}
```

The function can be found [here](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qstackedwidget.html#insertWidget) and you can actually see, if you read carefully how the inheritance works. So again `int QStackedWidget::insertWidget(int index, QWidget *widget)` from [official documentation](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qstackedwidget.html#insertWidget) solved the problem.  I hope this could solve the problem for other users. :)